Slow browser caused by CSP issues with script-src blob:
In our web application (Angular), we need the camera to scan a QR code. However, for some time now, we have seen an error

Failed to construct 'Worker': Access to the script at 'blob:https://somehing.ch/38a37229-2d47-4b12-a8f1-0080265163f9' is denied by the document's Content Security Policy.

with some users.
To fix this, we added "blob:" to the CSP script-src.
To our surprise, this caused the browser to become very slow for some users (in some cases, up to 30 seconds response time after pressing a button). This did not happen to all users but only to a few. Most of the problems happends in chromium browsers. Deleting the cookies provided a solution in each case.
We tried to solve the problem, by removing "blob:" from the script-src and added
worker-src 'self' blob: *.something.ch
But it looks like we have performance problems as soon we add "blob:" to CSP. Does anyone have an explanation for this?

sounds like it's computing the hash.  (does this include integrity hash in markup?)  Is blob needed here?

The problem was as follows: We already had a web worker in our code through a third-party library without realizing it. However, this was previously blocked by the missing CSP entry, and we didn’t notice it.
With the new CSP entry, the web worker was now allowed to run, which led to very long loading times on pages with many table entries. Deleting the cookies and local storage, reset the number of entries in the table back to 10, which made the problem disappear.
To make matters worse, our IT department overrides the CSP in our test systems, which prevented us from reproducing the issue.
Conclusion: Never trust customer support, and not our IT test systems either!
